# display current date base on cell value vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

kindly disregard my first two questions :D
I've already found a solution for it

but for this one it's kind a bit hard for me, since I'm not good at macro especially on its Condition function.

I have this conditional code for my macro, I don't know how to display it the current date if the cell value is equivalent to **DONE**

```
If Range("I5:I1222") = "Done" Then
    With Range("K5:K1222, M5:M1222")
        .Value = Date
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
End If
```

I have a drop down list that contains

```
Done
Cancelled
Ongoing
```

if the user choice done the current date will display on two cell (col I and col M)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `Range("I5:I1222") = "Done"`, as the program should tell you when you try to run it.

Seems like you want to check the cell of your list, so you should use `Range().value`.
Say that your drop-down list is on `I5`, then you can use `If Range("I5").value = "Done" Then`

This will however print the date 2500 times, and that doesn't seem like something you want.

My best guess from this, is that you have one drop-down on each row, and you want to check them, and print the date on the current row.

Do do that, you would have to loop through the range `I5:I1222` and check each value, like:

```
Dim listR As Range, cell As Range
Set listR = Range("I5:I1222")
For Each cell In listR
  If cell.Value2 = "Done" Then
    With Application.Union(Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2), Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 4))
        .Value2 = Date
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
  End If
Next cell
```

But this would replace every old date being set previously. And that doesn't seem like something you want to do.
You could add a condition, to check if a date is already there, for example changing the `if`to `If cell.Value2 = "Done" And Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, 2) = "" Then` or similar.

You could also call the sub as a worksheet_change event, which would allow it to add the date as soon as you select "Done" from the drop down menu, and only write to that specific row.

This can be done by putting the code directly on the sheet, instead of in a module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Application.Intersect(Range(Target.Address), Range("I5:I1222")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value2 = "Done" Then
        With Application.Union(Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 2), Range(Target.Address).Offset(0, 4))
            .Value2 = Date
            .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        End With
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: **#Christofer**,,  Worksheet Change Event is working nicely ,,, You deserve 10 ☺

Comment: it worked perfect. but what if I have a protected worksheet and column K is uneditable

Comment: @gee if you have a protected worksheet, you should probably add `ActiveSheet.Unprotect ` before any edits, and then  `ActiveSheet.Protect` after – including whatever parameters you need, like password and such. It's not a bad idea to put the Protect part in error handling, as an error after `unprotect`but before `protect`would leave the worksheet unprotected.

Comment: is this still work if I tried to create new workbook? example I have a button that will create new workbook and save as new if clicked. all the codes in macro will apply in the new workbook but it will save as **.xlsx**

Comment: @gee Macros won't work in xlsx, so if you put this in a xlsx file, it just won't do anything.